# Overriding static properties in F# with extension methods

Tags: f#

F# extension methods can be defined on types with the same name and type signature as existing instance and static methods to effectively override the default implementation of these methods, however I can't get this to work on static properties.

In particular, I'm trying to create an extension method for `DateTime` that returns a more precise time as follows:

```
#nowarn "51"

open System

module DateTimeExtensions =

    open System.Runtime.InteropServices

    [<DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)>]
    extern void private GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(int64*)

    type System.DateTime with
        // example showing that static methods can be overridden
        static member IsLeapYear(_: DateTime) =
            printfn "Using overridden IsLeapYear!"
            true

        // more accurate UtcNow method (note: not supported by older OS versions)
        static member UtcNow =
            printfn "Using overridden UtcNow!"
            let mutable fileTime = 0L
            GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(&&fileTime)
            DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(fileTime)
```

However, the output when executing

```
open DateTimeExtensions
let _ = DateTime.IsLeapYear(DateTime.UtcNow)
```

is just

```
Using overridden IsLeapYear!
```

which shows that the static method 'override' is working, but not the static property.

(Note: I'm using F# 4.0)

Comment: Is there any reason you want this to work? Since this will only work in code that imports your module, you might as well just have a differently named function.

Answer (score 3):

This statement seems to be incorrect:

> F# extension methods can be defined on types with the same name and
>   type signature as existing instance and static methods to effectively
>   override the default implementation of these methods, however I can't
>   get this to work on static properties.

No, they don't override.

You might be confused because in fact your signature of `IsLeapYear` is wrong, it should take an integer, that's why it works I mean you are not overriding anything, just adding a new (extension) method.

If you try it with the original signature you'll see that it doesn't work either:

```
type System.DateTime with
    // example showing that static methods can NOT be overridden
    static member IsLeapYear(_: int) =
        printfn "Using overridden IsLeapYear!"
        false

> DateTime.IsLeapYear(2000);;
val it : bool = true
```

Which is consistent with the behavior of the static property extension.

Anyway I'm not sure why it was decided not to override, if there was such decision at all when designing the language. I think it would be an interesting feature and if there is a good reason not to implement it at least it should emit a warning saying that since the method already exists it will never be called.

Maybe I will open an issue or a suggestion for the F# compiler.

Comment: You did open an issue, or at least opened the discussion: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/3582#issuecomment-333663962