# What is the best way to enhance Map in F# such that it reports the key when raising KeyNotFoundException?

Tags: f#

I find it impractical that F# Maps do not report the key in KeyNotFoundExceptions:

```
let m = Map.empty<int,string>
m.[2]

>> KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary. // ok, and which key?
```

The problem certainly does not arise in this example where the key is present but when the exception comes out from a running program. I tried to extend Item, but extensions do not override (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46251858/857848)

```
module Ext =
    type Map<'k, 'v when 'k : comparison> with
    member o.Item k = // with better exception
        match o.TryGetValue k with
        | true, value -> value
        | false,_ -> failwithf "key not found in map: %A" k
open Ext
```

I will wrap Map, to get it done, but wondered if there is a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's any practical way to do this, and I suspect that wrapping `Map` is more trouble than it's worth. Instead, I would consider a custom operator:

```
let (@) map key =
    match map |> Map.tryFind key with
        | Some value -> value
        | None -> failwithf "key not found in map: %A" key

let m = Map.empty<int,string>
m @ 2
```

Comment: I would like to change all calls in my codebase without changing that. I realize that it is so often that just knowing directly which key it was would help a lot. Wrapping would be less than adding an operator.

Comment: Mostly agree with @brianberns on this one. You should use `Map.tryFind` or augment it with an operator wherever you are looking for an item that might not exist. You should also handle the None case properly instead of throwing an exception. `Map.[key]` should be used in cases you are certain the key exists and the exception should represent an unrecoverable error. It might be a pain to refactor all the existing uses but once it's done you won't have to worry about it again.